# How can i add this script in php

Tags: php

am trying to find out how to add this script to my php file , as i try echo it ,its not working.

am sure there is a way to add this, its my first time adding these scripts to php file ,maybe il learn something today and remmeber it thanks.

```
var counter = 1;
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function () {
    var newcontent= 'Refresh nr:'+counter;
    $('#divID').html(newcontent);
    counter++;
}, 5000);
```

and the html div  this is not needed to add to php as i have own div in php file

```
<div id="divID"></div>
```

Comment: where is the php file wazza?

Comment: That is a javascript script, it going into the html page using `<script>` tags

Comment: @wazza, did you get what you need?

Answer (score 2):

Close the php tags, open a script tag, paste your script there, close your script tag, re-open your php tag. ;)

I recommend putting your js at the end of the file tho.

```
<?php
    // your php here
?>

<div id="divID"></div>
<?php
    // some php if you want to
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  //Your javascript here
  var counter = 1;
  var auto_refresh = setInterval(
  function () {
    var newcontent= 'Refresh nr:'+counter;
    $('#divID').html(newcontent);
    counter++;
  }, 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you won't put javascript in your php file... But if there's no other solution:

```
<?php

echo"
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    var counter = 1;
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function () {
       var newcontent= 'Refresh nr:'+counter;
       $('#divID').html(newcontent);
       counter++;
}, 5000);        
</script>
";
```

Answer (score 1):

In `PHP` pass `js` code into variable

```
<?php 
    $script = "<script type='text/javascript'>
    var counter = 1;
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function () {
      var newcontent= 'Refresh nr:'+counter;
      $('#divID').html(newcontent);
      counter++;
    }, 5000);  </script>";
?>
```

In `HTML` where you want to show/add

```
<html>
<head>
   <?php echo  $script; ?>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it like this or you can put `<script>` part in the head of your page or in js file and include in page.

```
<?php
// code
?>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var counter = 1;
   var auto_refresh = setInterval(
   function () {
       var newcontent= 'Refresh nr:'+counter;   
       $('#divID').html(newcontent);
       counter++;
   }, 5000);
});
</script>
<div id="divID"></div>
```

Note: you also need jquery. If you don't use one you can include this in your page also

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

I just tested it and it's working perfectly. Currently my counter is

```
Refresh nr:51
```